# How does the Opcache algorithm work?

Tags: php, opcache

I've enabled OPcache on my server. It's a shared hosting server that serves ±30 websites. There are 2 high-traffic websites that use Symfony2.

Is OPcache smart enough to cache to most of those high-traffic websites and not fill its cache with the other, not so important, websites?

Or is it determined on first come, first serve?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there's pretty much a dearth of decent documentation on how opcode caches work, but hopefully this will enter the PHP mainstream soon.  In the meantime, I have done this write-up which should help: [The Zend Engine and opcode caching](https://github.com/TerryE/opcache/wiki/The-Zend-Engine-and-opcode-caching).  Note that is in the wiki of my own experimental fork, but this page is pure OPcache.

In terms of shared hosting infrastructure template, these are in general poorly served by opcode caches, and this is for a mix of reasons:

- Most caches (OPcache, APC, Xcache,...) use a shared memory cache, and when you map a R/W SMA into process space, then in practice you are giving full R/W access to *any* process which can map to it.  And this means that they have to share the same security domain. This is extremely problematic for shared hosting where the host provider typically wishes to enforce UID-based separation between the separate vhosts.
- None of the mainstream caches offer alternative (that is non-SMA) techniques.  My MLC OPcache demonstrator uses a file-based tier over OPcache and this give  ~80% of the performance improvements of native OPcache for shared hosters, but my aim of this fork isn't to set up in opposition to the core extension, but to de-risk these techniques to the point that at some point PHP will offer them as standard.
- I have found that there is very little interest amongst the PHP devs to improve the shared hosting SAPIs.  This perspective seems to be dominated by the view that if app hosters are interested in performance, then they should simply get themselves a VM and run a dedicated LAMP stack in this.
- However, if you are running **mod_php5** under Apache then enabling OPcache is simple and will typically give you a ~2x throughput increase for most complex applications such as MediaWiki, Drupal, and framework-based apps (Symphony2, Cake,...)
- For the ~10+ vhost sweet-spot, then the persistent GCI / FastGCI templates (**fpm** et al) can be set up to use OPcache with a per-UID SMA. Though configuration can be  difficult.

Sorry for the general answer, but you've asked a general Q and without more specific details, I can't give a more specific answer.

Comment: With opcache-status by Rasmus you can monitor which scripts are cached: [link](https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status)

Comment: Yes, Rasmus' script is a start, but you should really configure an access-controlled virtual directory to execute this from and then use `opcache.restrict_api` to limit use of the OPcache API to this directory.  There are also a few functional holes in the reporting API which I an trying to fix in the 5.6 release.

Comment: I wish one could truly release a script using invalidation so others can take its place. Now it just stays there but invalid, which is crazy. No real way to manage OPcache using our own customizations.